# Can't access conda after changing name of mac user account

Tags: macos, path, conda

When I first got my Macbook Pro, I set it up where my home folder was named

`/Users/monicaheddneck/`

I installed all the software I needed, like python, etc, and went about my business.

Last night, I decided to change the name of my folder to simply

`/Users/monica/`

and did it [this way](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548).

Fine.

Today, I decided to run jupyter notebook for the millionth time, and realized I may have borked all paths for all the libraries I have...and who knows what else.

For example,

`conda --version`

tells me I don't even have conda installed:

`-bash: conda: command not found`

My question: is there any way to fix the broken path to conda?

I am using Mac High Sierra, version 10.13.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the conda installer, it asks if you want to add and export line with the path to conda in your `bashrc` file. My guess is that it wasn't updated when you changed the name of your account.

Have a look at your bashrc (hidden file) which should be in your home and update it as necessary ! The line should look like this:

```
export PATH="/Users/monicaheddneck/xxxconda/bin:$PATH"
```

and should be fixed appropriatly:

```
export PATH="/Users/monica/xxxconda/bin:$PATH"
```

You will then have to source your new bashrc file or restart a terminal.

Comment: sure enough, that was it. I should have been smart enough to at least check that location. Thanks!